# JQuery Mobile dynamically added pages are unthemed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm currently trying to dynamically generate pages from a JSON file. I can generate the page, but when I visit the page afterwards, the page is unthemed save for the back button. Here's my code for generating the page:

```
function generateClassPage(dept, cNumber) {
    $("body").append('<div data-role="page" data-control-title="' + majorArray[dept] + ' ' + cNumber + '" id=' + dept + 'p' + cNumber + '>');
    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('<div data-theme="b" data-role="header"><a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-transition="slidedown" data-theme="e" href="#page2" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>');
    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('<h3>' + majorArray[parseInt(dept)] + ' ' + cNumber + '</h3>');
    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('</div><div data-role="content">');

    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('<h3>' + pageParameterArray.name + '</h3>');
    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('<div data-controltype="textblock"><p><span><strong>Units</strong>﻿: ' + pageParameterArray.units + '</span></p>');

    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('<p><span><strong>Pre-Requisites</strong>:&nbsp;</span></p>');
    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('<ul>');

    alert(pageParameterArray.prerequisites.length);

    if (pageParameterArray.prerequisites.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < pageParameterArray.prerequisites.length; i++) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://majors.uclastudentmedia.com/classes/',
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    pk: pageParameterArray.prerequisites[i]
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json_3) {
                    alert("JSON Length = " + json_3.length);
                    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('<li><span>' + majorArray[parseInt(json_3[0]['fields']['department'])] + ' ' + json_3[0]['fields']['class_number'] + '</span></li>');
                }
            });
        }
    }    

    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('<li><span>n/a</span></li>');
    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('</ul>');

    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('</div></p></div></div></div>');
    alert("Page created!");
    $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).page();
}
```

When checking the HTML page afterwards, the div is properly added and can be accessed, but it's missing all of the JQuery mobile theme elements. Is there something I have to do to refresh the theme? Thanks!

Comment: try `.trigger('pagecreate')` instead of `.page()`. When/how do you inject a new page? on click or when an event triggers?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have a button bound to a click event, which launches another function which eventually launches this one.

Comment: I guess pages should be appended to page container. Try `$.mobile.pageContainer.append()` or pagecontainer, lowercase of letter C.

Comment: Still no. Are there any other more efficient ways to create new pages?

Comment: If you firebug, can you see pages in DOM enhanced?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to trigger the `create` event after the HTML is in place. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(document).trigger('create');
```

Note this needs to run after all the HTML has been created, otherwise it won't work properly.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm using the command after all of the HTML is appended, but the page is still unthemed

Comment: @user2884505 It may be that it hasn't finished rendering the HTML when the method is called. Try running the command from the browser console.

Comment: I tried both trigger('create') and trigger('pagecreate') in the console, but neither seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning an id attribute to the page div you are appending then do:

```
$("#pageid").trigger('create');
```

directly on that div using your assigned id in place of #pageid

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, no luck. Just checking, I should attach all of the page elements to the page div and not body, right?

Comment: It appears you have an extra </div></p> in this line: $('#' + dept + 'p' + cNumber).append('</div></p></div></div></div>'); this may be affecting enhancing the markup.Other than that your appended page looks good to me. Adding page elements to the page div with data-role="page" is correct,you are adding to that page in this way. The create event can be triggered on any element, in your case it would be the "page" as you want to enhance the entire page you appended. Check out here for more detail on this: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/injected-content-is-not-enhanced.html